# how to implement Random access data Virtualization in metro apps windows8?

Tags: microsoft-metro

I am having a large collection which is bind with a gridview. I just want it to be load when scroll bar moves.So that UI will not lock for large amount of time. I found it is done by data virtualization, But don't know how to implement.

Please help me!

Comment: Have you tired anything yourself?

Comment: I have found something on internet about incremental data virtualization but not found anything for random access. Here is links                             http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:e-ZbZ3EJ_mEJ:answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/metro/csharpvb.aspx%3FID%3D8f7a1a5b-6a8d-4971-8f38-2075295298b5+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in <http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:e-ZbZ3EJ_mEJ:answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/metro/csharpvb.aspx?ID%3D8f7a1a5b-6a8d-4971-8f38-2075295298b5+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in>